# Abi filter - shadowed by one or more APKs with higher version codes

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a media player application that is using vlc library. VLC have jni libs for 'armeabi-v7a' & 'arm64-v8a'. 
Now to reduce the size, i wanted to upload apks for both these architectures separately, so i made flavors in gradle. The flavoring code in gradle looks like this: 
flavorDimensions "default"

```
productFlavors {

    arm64 {
        versionCode 73
        versionName "1.0.4"
        ndk.abiFilter "arm64-v8a"
    }
    arm {
        versionCode 74
        versionName "1.0.4"
        ndk.abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
    }
}
```

The apks i get have **libs** folder that contain their respective files, arm64 for arm64-v8a and similarly for armv7 for armeabi-v7a, both apks have different size.

Now The **Problem** is when i upload both these apks to playstore in Beta or alpha version i get the error:

"*This APK will not be served to any users because it is completely shadowed by one or more APKs with higher version codes.*"

If i upload v7 after v8, v8 says that it will be shadowed by higher version (which is v7).

any ideas why is this happening , when there's libs folder present on the basis of which playstore identifies the difference of flavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the error.

Since v8 is backward compatible, armv8 can also run v7 apk. So the v8 apk should have higher version code than v7 so user having armv8 architecture should be served with v8 apk. So i had to make it something like this:

```
productFlavors {

    arm64 {
        versionCode 75 // <- higher version code than v7
        versionName "1.0.4"
        ndk.abiFilter "arm64-v8a"
    }
    arm {
        versionCode 74
        versionName "1.0.4"
        ndk.abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
    }
}
```